# Is there any way I can reference the previous line in a file?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, getline, delete-file

```
void del(fstream& file, string line) {

 ofstream temp;
 temp.open("temp.txt");
 string delsearch;


 cout << "Delete by name (case-sensitive!): ";
 cin >> delsearch;
 cout << endl;


 while (getline(file, line)){


      if (line.substr(0, 5) == "Name:"){
            line.erase(0, 5);
            line = "Name:" + line;
      }

            if (line.find(delsearch) != string::npos){

                 line.erase(0, sizeof(line));
                 getline(file, line);
                 line.erase(0, sizeof(line));
                 getline(file, line);
                 line.erase(0, sizeof(line));
                 getline(file, line);
                 line.erase(0, sizeof(line));

                 cout << "DELETED!" << endl << endl;
            }

            temp << line << endl;
      }

file.close();
temp.close();
remove("phonebook.txt");
rename("temp.txt", "phonebook.txt");

 }
```

I'm trying to give my phonebook read/write program a delete function, and I've gotten this far. Here, I'm creating a temp file to replace the existing input phonebook file, as I understand this is the most common way to delete lines in files.

The format for each contact is as follows:

```
Name: John Doe                                            
Phone: 123-456-789                     
Email: jd@email.com
```

And I'd like to delete all three entries, and top whitespace per contact. The problem is, my function here deletes everything but the top whitespace. I'm very new to c++, I don't know how to go about fixing this anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: istream has tellg, which gives you the current character position and seekg, which moves the pointer around within the file.  Of course in order to go back a line, you'd have to have marked the previous line start position with a tellg, in order to seekg back to it.

Comment: `line.erase(0, sizeof(line));` sizeof does not give you the number of characters in the string. You must use `line.size()` for that.

Comment: I looked up some usage of (in the case of ostream) tellp and seekp, and I'm still not too sure how to implement this sort of thing into my while loop.

Comment: Also I can't see the point of making line a parameter, as you overwrite it with new data.

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing that out, I've gotten rid of that now.